# How to select current date from dynamic calendar in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, calendar

The calendar display date from current to next upcoming date. i need to select current date when every time I run the script.

Calendar looks like this: https://www.screencast.com/t/EWjncok2Anv

I tried with below code, but didn't help me:

```
     DateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd"); 
     Date date2 = new Date();

     String today = dateFormat2.format(date2); 

     //find the calendar
     WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.id("qs_startdate"));  
     List<WebElement> columns=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("div"));  

     //comparing the text of cell with today's date and clicking it.
     for (WebElement cell : columns)
     {
        if (cell.getText().equals(today))
        {
           cell.click();
           break;
        }
     }
```

Comment: You have provided a screencast. A screencast does not expose the HTML code under it. If you want help with parting HTML for Selenium, you need to provide relevant HTML snippets or else a link to the UI (if it is public and safe).

Comment: The approach seems quite good. Can i know what error message you are getting. Also print cell.getText() values in the for loop for debugging

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String date = dateFormat.format(today);
```